# Why is there bijection between all multiples of $d$ in mod $N$ and the image of $f$ here?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I am confused about why there is bijection between the image of $f$ and the set of all multiple of $d$ in mod $N$ in the below question:

> If $f(x)=a x(\bmod N)$ where $N>1$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(a, N)=d$, what is the size of the following set:
> $$
> \{f(0) \bmod N, \ldots, f(N-1) \bmod N\}
> $$
> (Answer could be in terms of $a, d$ and $N$.)
> **Answer**: $N / d$. It is all possible multiples of $d$ in $\{0, \ldots, N-1\}$.

I am wondering what the logic behind concluding that the image of $f$ is all possible multiples of $d$ in mod $N$. $ax$, before we take it mod $N$, is certainly a multiple of $d$; but what is the reason why it is still a multiple of $d$ when we take it mod $N$? Doesn't the common $d$ to both $N$ and $a$ divide it out? Also, why would a multiple of $d$ in mod $N$ have a pre-image?

Essentially, I am wondering how we argue for bijection between the image of $f$ and the set of all multiple of $d$ in mod $N$.

Comment: There isn't a bijection; it's a surjection. Consider the case $a=4, N=10, d=2$. Then we obtain the sequence $(0,4,8,2,6,0,4,8,2,6) \pmod{10}$ for $x=0 \cdots 9$. Every element in the defined set is mapped from two elements of the sequence. Now imagine that $(a, N)=1$. Clearly the set has $N$ elements, as there are no matches. If $d=2$, though, every second residue is skipped--and since $d \mid N$, we know that $a(N/2) \equiv 0 \pmod N$. Hence the same residues that were previously skipped will be skipped on the second pass, giving $N/2$ elements. That scales up for any $d$.